# If values in 3 columns match say Exact Match-MS Excel

Tags: excel, match

This is what my data looks like

[image: iMAGE 1. CLICK]

basically, if all values in columns A,B,C are same for two rows ( such as for Row 1 and Row 3 ) In column D it should say "Exact Match" in D1 and D3.

I tried Countifs with an IF, but that doesnt work if all values are same.

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,A1,$B$1:$B$4,B1,$C$1:$C$4,C1)>1,"Exact Match","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both for that very timely response. I really appreciate it. @bruce, that is exactly what I was doing, as I had mentioned in my question but I was equating it to the number of Rows instead of just >1. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you're looking for matches in either column A, B or C?

Would something as simple as this work?

```
=IF(A1=B1,"EXACT MATCH",IF(A1=C1,"EXACT MATCH", IF(B1=C1,"EXACT MATCH", "")))
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking to compare cells in the same column, not within each row.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted all 3 columns to match. You did point me in the right direction. Really thankful to you.